# panel encountered a problem while loading "Clock Applet Factory:: ClockApplet

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, desktop-environments

[image: Error snapshot]

I am facing the error in above snapshot frequently on my system.
What is a solution for this all my tool bar and related icons disappear after this in panel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, that's a sign that something is wrong with the applet's configuration. Delete it and re-add it. (That's an entirely un-scientific answer, from my own experience)